# Decimal String to hexadecimal String

Tags: java

I have a `String` encoded in this kind of format:

```
223175087923687075112234402528973166755
```

The decoded string looks like:

```
a7e5f55e1dbb48b799268e1a6d8618a3
```

I need to convert from Decimal to Hexadecimal, but the input number is much bigger than the `int` or `long` types can handle, so how can I convert this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use BigInteger :

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("223175087923687075112234402528973166755");
System.out.println(big.toString(16));
```

Output :

```
a7e5f55e1dbb48b799268e1a6d8618a3
```